# how to make your data horizontal

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 identical data in 2 row and I intend to make this data become 1 row. for example I have this data sample :

```
Name    Status  Bank
Thung   Active  ABC Bank
Thung   Hold    ABC Bank
```

can I make something like this  ?

```
Name    Status 1    Bank 1  Status 2    Bank 2
Thung   Active  ABC Bank    Hold    ABC Bank
```

Comment: This is called a Pivot or Cross Tab (I recommend the latter). There are 100's of examples of these on Stack Overflow. Have a look at them, and if you get stuck, please post your attempt(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7020a/8)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table MyTable(Name varchar(max),BStatus varchar(max),Bank varchar(max))
insert into MyTable (Name,BStatus,Bank)values('Thung','Active', 'ABC Bank')
insert into MyTable (Name,BStatus,Bank)values('Thung','Hold', 'ABC Bank')
```

**Query 1**:

```
with CTE AS (select *,
(CASE WHEN BStatus='Active' THEN BStatus  END) AS Status1,
(CASE WHEN BStatus = 'Hold' THEN BStatus END) AS Status2,
(CASE WHEN Bank='ABC Bank' THEN Bank END) AS Bank1,
(CASE WHEN Bank='ABC Bank' THEN Bank END) AS Bank2,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BStatus,Bank Order By Name) as rn
from MyTable
group by Name,BStatus,Bank              )

select c.Name
,max(c.Status1) AS Status1
,max(c.Status2) AS Status2
,max(c.Bank1) AS Bank1
,max(c.Bank2) AS Bank2
from cte c
where rn=1
group by c.Name,c.Bank
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7020a/8/0)**:

```
|  Name | Status1 | Status2 |    Bank1 |    Bank2 |
|-------|---------|---------|----------|----------|
| Thung |  Active |    Hold | ABC Bank | ABC Bank |
```

Comment: my data is already on a table and the bank isnt always the same so i cant use case for the bank since there aren't just 1 or 2 bank. Some name even have 3 banks with different status ( either active or hold). for your refrences, i put some part of the code that i used for this query.

 select distinct b.Name,
    g.Status,
    g.Bank
from client b
 left join BankAcc g
 on b.SeqID = g.FK

the problem is when someone have 1 or more different bank account because of the bank status the result will become 2 row with identical result like i mention above.

Comment: @MichaelThung can you please give us a complete description of your problem ?