# SQL Take two row values and transpose into two columns on one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to turn 2 rows into one by taking the different values in each row and transposing them into multiple columns, for example...

```
planID | jobNumber | qty | Name
  1    |    1      | 100 | abc
  1    |    2      | 100 | def
```

I want it to look like...

```
planID | jobNumber | qty | Name1 | Name2
  1    |    1      | 100 | abc   |  def
```

My query is a follows...

```
 SELECT DISTINCT s.planID, s.jobNumber, s.quantity, p.Name                  
              FROM schedule AS s
              JOIN partReferences as p ON p.yNumber = s.yNumber
```

I've tried using a pivot and case statement but can't seem to separate the name column properly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make your data horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605804/how-to-make-your-data-horizontal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  Something like this:

```
SELECT s.planID, MIN(s.jobNumber) as jobNumber,
       MIN(s.quantity) as quantity,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.jobNumber = 1 THEN p.Name END) as name_1,                
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.jobNumber = 2 THEN p.Name END) as name_2                
FROM schedule s JOIN
     partReferences p
     ON p.yNumber = s.yNumber
GROUP BY s.planID;
```

The logic for the second and third columns is not clear in the question, but this should return the result set you have specified.

Comment: Thank you that's worked perfectly. Is there a way I can extend this past 2 columns? I.e some Names could have 3 or more different values?

Comment: @mat1986 . . . You can add more names using the same structure.