# How to convert row data in column header and get corresponding data in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to convert the row into the header and get the data related to the row in SQL server. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for telling us and good luck. If you get stuck, then I suggest using you're favourite search engine to help find answers (if you add `site:stackoverflow.com` to the search you can specifically search this site(at least in Google) if you wanted). If you get stuck **after** you have tried, then please do post a question, showing your attempts, with sample data (not images) and explain why your attempt(s) didn't work. If you don't understand the resource you're reading, then post a question citing and referencing the resource, and tell us what you don't understand. Good luck!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make your data horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605804/how-to-make-your-data-horizontal)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(NAME VARCHAR(50),Age INT)

INSERT INTO #Temp([NAME], Age) VALUES('Joy',18)
INSERT INTO #Temp([NAME], Age) VALUES('Happy',25)
INSERT INTO #Temp([NAME], Age) VALUES('Jack',30)



SELECT 
[Joy],[Happy],[Jack]
FROM
(SELECT NAME,Age
FROM #Temp) AS TempTbl  
PIVOT
(
    AVG(Age)
    FOR [name] IN ([Joy],[Happy],[Jack])
) AS PivotTable
```

**Note:-** you can use pivot for getting column name in Header......you have pre-define your header column name...

**Output**

```
Joy Happy Jack
----------------
 18  25    30
```