# Is there a way to create a "pivot group" of columns with t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

This seems like a common need but, unfortunately, I can't find a solution.

Assume you have a query that outputs the following content:

```
| TimeFrame  | User       | Metric1 | Metric2 |
+------------+------------+---------+---------+
| TODAY      | John Doe   | 10      | 20      |
| MONTHTODAY | John Doe   | 100     | 200     |
| TODAY      | Jack Frost | 15      | 25      |
| MONTHTODAY | Jack Frost | 150     | 250     |
```

What I need as output after a pivot is data that looks like this:

```
| User       | TODAY_Metric1 | TODAY_Metric2 | MONTHTODAY_Metric1 | MONTHTODAY_Metric2 |
+------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| John Doe   | 10            | 20            |100                 | 200                |
| Jack Frost | 15            | 25            |150                 | 250                |
```

Note that I'm doing the pivoting on `TimeFrame`, however, columns `Metric1` and `Metric2` remain columns but are grouped by time frame values.

Can this be done within standard `PIVOT` syntax or will I need to write a more complex query to pull this data together in a result set specific to my needs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make your data horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605804/how-to-make-your-data-horizontal)

Comment: The reason this is a struggle is because you have violated 1NF with repeating groups (Metric1, Metric2). If this was normalized this would be painless. But the conditional aggregation below is the best way to deal with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select
    user,
    sum(case when timeframe = 'TODAY' then Metric_1 end) TODAY_Metric1,
    sum(case when timeframe = 'TODAY' then Metric_2 end) TODAY_Metric2,
    sum(case when timeframe = 'MONTHTODAY' then Metric_1 end) MONTHTODAY_Metric1,
    sum(case when timeframe = 'MONTHTODAY' then Metric_2 end) MONTHTODAY_Metric2
from mytable
group by user
```

I tend to prefer the conditional aggregation technique over the vendor-specific implementations, because:

- I find it simpler to understand and maintain
- it is cross-RDBMS (so you can easily port it to some other database if needed)
- it usually performs as well, or even better than vendor implementation (that usually rely upon it under the hood)

Comment: Ugh, my head isn't screwed on straight today.  This is the answer.  This is what happens (I forget) when my job spreads me across to many different types of responsibilities.  Thanks for the reminder.