# How make a select on a MS SQL Server table to show some of its column data in a row and use sum function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a MS SQL Server table as below:

[image]

and I need to change it into below format with TSQL:

[image]

How can I do this? Any help will be appriciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make your data horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605804/how-to-make-your-data-horizontal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want a PIVOT ...

```
SELECT title,  
    [type1] AS type1,  
    [type2] AS type2  
FROM  
    (SELECT title, [type], [number])   
    AS Source  
PIVOT  
(  
    sum([number])  
FOR   
[[type]]   
    IN ( [type1], [type2])  
) AS PVT;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank You. That worked. But you imagine that there is too much different items in Type column for example: type1 , type2, type3, type4, type5, .... . How can I handle these too much items???

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    title, 
    max(case when [type] = 'type1' then [number] end) [type1],
    max(case when [type] = 'type2' then [number] end) [type2]
from mytable
group by title
```

If you may possibly have more than one record for a given `(title, type)` tuple, you might want to use another aggregate function than `max()`, like `sum()` or `avg()`.