# Main and secondary manager of an employee

Tags: sql-server

I want to regroup the main and secondary manager of an employee :

```
EmployeeName    ManagerStatus Manager
Mario           Primary       Rodrigo
Mario           Secondary     Thomas
```

I want to make something like below :

```
EmployeeName    PrimaryManager  SecondaryManager
Mario           Rodrigo         Thomas
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make your data horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605804/how-to-make-your-data-horizontal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation :

```
select EmployeeName, 
       max(case when ManagerStatus = 'Primary' then Manager end) as PrimaryManager,
       max(case when ManagerStatus = 'Secondary' then Manager end) asSecondaryManager     
from table t
group by EmployeeName;
```

This assumes employee will have single `primary` or `secondary` manager.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below way. Another way is to [PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
SELECT EmployeeName
    ,max(PrimaryManager) AS PrimaryManager
    ,max(SecondaryManager) AS SecondaryManager
FROM (
    SELECT EmployeeName
        ,CASE ManagerStatus
            WHEN 'Primary'
                THEN Manager
            END AS PrimaryManager
        ,CASE ManagerStatus
            WHEN 'Secondary'
                THEN Manager
            END AS SecondaryManager
    FROM MyTable
    ) a
GROUP BY EmployeeName
```

[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=110af426805656a39ecd52a62da227a9)

Comment: Requesting to retract the down vote as per the updated answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/43ec8/5)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table MyTable(EmployeeName varchar(max),ManagerType varchar(max),Manager varchar(max))
insert into MyTable (EmployeeName,ManagerType,Manager)values
('Mario','Primary', 'Rodrigo'),('Mario','Secondary', 'Thomas')
```

**Query 1**:

```
with CTE AS (select *,
(CASE WHEN ManagerType='Primary' THEN Manager END) AS PrimaryManager,
(CASE WHEN ManagerType = 'Secondary' THEN Manager END) AS SecondaryManager,

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ManagerType,Manager

                   Order By EmployeeName DESC) as rn
from MyTable
group by EmployeeName,ManagerType,Manager             )

select c.EmployeeName
,max(c.PrimaryManager) AS PrimaryManager
,max(c.SecondaryManager) AS SecondaryManager

from cte c
where rn=1
group by c.EmployeeName
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/43ec8/5/0)**:

```
| EmployeeName | PrimaryManager | SecondaryManager |
|--------------|----------------|------------------|
|        Mario |        Rodrigo |           Thomas |
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `rn` ?

Comment: @Squirrel for historical purpose if there is a start and end date for each manager-managee allocation

Comment: You are light years ahead. I don't see that mention in OP's question