# SQL Server : group by userId - merge 2 rows into 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

When I query a user by `UserName` I get two rows but I would like to merge them into one row. For example,

Current result:

[image]

Desired result:

[image: into]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make your data horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605804/how-to-make-your-data-horizontal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do aggregation :

```
select userid, username, 
       max(case when phonetype = 'primary' then phonenumber end) as primary_no,
       max(case when phonetype = 'secondary' then phonenumber end) as secondary_no
from t
group by userid, username;
```